# How to get script to run through every line of txt file and perform a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a `script` that goes through every stock ticker in a `txt-file`, and runs through `googlefinance`to to gather all of its historical data and outputs it into a `CSV-file`. I know this should not be that difficult, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong in this code. It works fine for the first stock, then crashes. I have an assumption that it has something to do with the `\n` but I tried the `splitlines()` function and a bunch of other things.

**My code:**

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
from datetime import datetime
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from yahoo_finance import Share

sp500 = open('sp500tickers.txt').read().splitlines()

for x in sp500:

    share = Share(sp500[x])
    print (share.get_price())

    start = dt.datetime(2001,1,1)
    end = dt.datetime(2017,1,1)

    df = web.DataReader(share, 'google', start, end)
    df.to_csv(''+x+'.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
```

**Text file**:

```
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ACN
ATVI
AYI
ADBE
AAP
AES
AET
AMG
AFL
A
APD
AKAM
ALK
ALB
ALXN
ALLE
AGN
ADS
LNT
ALL
GOOGL
GOOG
MO
AMZN
AEE
AAL
...
```

**Edited code:**

```
with open('p1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()

        share = Share(line)
        style.use('ggplot')
        print (share.get_price())

        start = dt.datetime(2001,1,1)
        end = dt.datetime(2017,1,1)

        df = web.DataReader(share, 'google', start, end)
        df.to_csv(''+line+'.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
```

Comment: Since you're already using `pandas` why don't you use `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: Meaning...? Turn my list of tickers into a csv and then run it? I will end up running into the same issue.

Comment: Your list of tickers is a txt file. A txt file can be imported via `read_csv()`. You're already constructing dataframes of prices so I don't understand why this is being done in multiple steps.

Comment: Ok, so then how would I go about reading every line of the CSV to perform this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `for-loop`, x is not an iterator. x is the value itself, so change this line:

```
share = Share(sp500[x])
```

to

```
share = Share(x)
```

And for reading the file, you can read each line at a time instead of reading all at once, as the following:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        #your code
```

Comment: Can you help me with the second part of that function? So it works for retrieving the prices quite simply, but I get a couple of errors.. After 308 lines of the txt file, I get an HTTP error so I'm assuming the website I am calling it viewing me as a robot.. But my main concern is this error: `return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))
TypeError: object of type 'Share' has no len()` - Which returns when I am trying to convert all the historical data into a CSV. How can I go about solving this?

Comment: what is `seq`?  can you post the whole function?

Comment: I don't have seq written anywhere in my function. I'm assuming that has something to do with the package I am using. My function is exactly what I have up there right now.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think the issue is that `web.DataReader()` takes a `list` as the first parameter, but you are passing it a `Share`.  try moving that line out of your for loop and pass in `sp500` as the first paramater, so `web.DataReader(sp500, 'google', start, end)`

Comment: Was it about passing a list as the first parameter?

Comment: Yes, so I passed `line` instead and it worked. Quick question: I'm getting the error - `print (line + " " + share.get_price())
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType` when I reach a certain line in my list. Is there anyway I can say, skip the error ones? Or, convert NoneType to string?

Comment: you can use `try: str(x) except TypeError: pass` to skip the error ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147374/discussion-between-mitchell-and-moe-a).

Answer (score 0):

1) what you do here:

```
sp500 = open('sp500tickers.txt').read().splitlines()
```

is reading the whole file into memory, which is bad idea for big files - do this instead:

```
with open('sp500tickers.txt') as sp500:
```

2) in this line:

```
share = Share(sp500[i])
```

where does `i` come from?

Comment: Sorry, that should be an x. I uploaded an earlier version of my code. Fixing now.

Comment: Still wrong. `x` **is** the line from your text file, not an index. It should be just `share = Share(x)`

Comment: Ok, so getting every price is working now.. My issue now becomes - why is the historical data not being able to collect?

Comment: Error: `TypeError: object of type 'Share' has no len()`